# Refresh Listview Item inside Activity A from Fragments B in MultiPan

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

In a **Master/Detail Flow** template  I have a activity A contains a custom list view that displays the names of the articles and the total tax after click on the items the activity B displays a datagrid that contains the details of the items with the ability to simply remove an item or change I want refresh the value of the total tax in the list view to show the new value after the item is updated

the code of update the SQLite Database and the Datagrid is :

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        artiouv.set_prix(Float.valueOf(EPrixU.getText().toString()));
                        artiouv.set_quantite(Float.valueOf(EQte.getText().toString()));
                        db.UpdateArticleOuv(artiouv);                           
                        DataTable.DataRow drRow;
                        drRow = dtDataSource.getRow(indexList);
                        drRow.set(0, Fo.get_ref());
                        drRow.set(0, Fo.get_ref());
                        Double TTC = 0.00;
                        Double THT = 0.00;
                        Double TVA = 0.00;
                        TVA=Fo.get_quantite()*Fo.get_prix()*Fo.get_tva()*0.01;
                        THT=Fo.get_quantite()*Fo.get_prix();
                        TTC=THT+TVA;
                        drRow.set(0, Fo.get_ref());
                        drRow.set(1, Fo.get_nom());
                        drRow.set(2, Fo.get_desc());
                        drRow.set(3, db.GetUniteById(Fo.get_unite()));
                        drRow.set(4,db.GetTypeByid(Fo.get_type()));
                        drRow.set(5, formatter.format(Float.valueOf(EPrixU.getText().toString())) +"$");
                        drRow.set(6, Float.valueOf(EQte.getText().toString())+"");
                        drRow.set(7, Fo.get_tva()+"");
                        drRow.set(8, formatter.format(TTC) +"$");
                        dtDataSource.update(drRow);
                        dg.setDataSource(dtDataSource);
                        dg.refresh();   


                        }
                    })
```

Help me please .

Answer (score 0):

In order to communicate between your `Fragment B` and your `Activity A` you can use an interface with all the methods you need:

#### Interface (example)

```
public interface IRefrestListView {
    public void onItemUpdate(/*Values to pass*/);
}
```

Then **in your Activity** implement the interface as well as the method:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements IRefreshListView{

    //...

    @Override
    public void onItemUpdate(/*Values to pass*/){
      /* TODO: Update item, refresh ListView */
    }
}
```

And finally **in your Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    private IRefrestListView callback;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            callback = (IRefrestListView) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement IRefrestListView");
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever you wann call the method on your Main-Activity simple do something like this:

```
callback.onItemUpdate(/*Values to pass*/);
```